# ng option combine two dynamic fields

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I am displaying two drop downs and the ng-option for second drop down is dynamic but how can I combine two dynamic fields to be displayed in drop down, I know how to do that for a static field. Please take a look at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LfEMw/5/

View:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="FeatureTypeDropdown" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="option1" ng-options="ft as ft.type for ft in featuretype">
        <option value="">Select a Feature Type...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="Select1" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="factory.geography.county" ng-options="c as c[option1.displayName] for c in option1.data" multiple>
        <option value="">Select a Feature...</option>
    </select>    
    <br/><br/>
        I want second drop down to display in this format when any feature is selected<br/>
    <select id="Select2" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="factory.geography.county" ng-options="c as c.CountyName + '-' + c.countyNumber for c in County" multiple>
        <option value="">Select a Feature...</option>
    </select>    

</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.County = [{ CountyName: 'C1', countyNumber: '01' }, { CountyName: 'C2', countyNumber: '02' }, { CountyName: 'C3', countyNumber: '03' }, { CountyName: 'C4', countyNumber: '04' }];
    $scope.Municipality = [{ MunicipalityName: 'M1', MunicipalityNumber: '01' }, { MunicipalityName: 'M2', MunicipalityNumber: '02' }, { MunicipalityName: 'M3', MunicipalityNumber: '03' }];

    $scope.Districts = [{ DistrictsName: 'D1', DistrictsNumber: '01' }, { DistrictsName: 'D2', DistrictsNumber: '02' }, { DistrictsName: 'D3', DistrictsNumber: '03' }];

        $scope.featuretype = [
            { type: 'County', data:$scope.County, displayName:'CountyName' },
             { type: 'Municipality', data:$scope.Municipality, displayName:'MunicipalityName'},
             { type: 'District', data:$scope.Districts, displayName:'DistrictsName'}
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update:

Oh! I get it now, you want something like this:

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yu6terfq/)

### Custom `$filter` + controller

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.filter('customInterpolate', function($interpolate){
    return function(context, expression){
        return $interpolate(expression)(context);  
    }
})
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.County = [{ CountyName: 'C1', countyNumber: '01' }, { CountyName: 'C2', countyNumber: '02' }, { CountyName: 'C3', countyNumber: '03' }, { CountyName: 'C4', countyNumber: '04' }];
    $scope.Municipality = [{ MunicipalityName: 'M1', MunicipalityNumber: '01' }, { MunicipalityName: 'M2', MunicipalityNumber: '02' }, { MunicipalityName: 'M3', MunicipalityNumber: '03' }];

    $scope.Districts = [{ DistrictsName: 'D1', DistrictsNumber: '01' }, { DistrictsName: 'D2', DistrictsNumber: '02' }, { DistrictsName: 'D3', DistrictsNumber: '03' }];

        $scope.featuretype = [
            { type: 'County', data:$scope.County, displayExpression:'{{CountyName}}-{{countyNumber}}' },
            { type: 'Municipality', data:$scope.Municipality, displayExpression:'{{MunicipalityName}} whatever {{MunicipalityNumber}}'},
            { type: 'District', data:$scope.Districts, displayExpression:'{{DistrictsName}} different {{DistrictsNumber}}'}
    ];
});
```

### Template

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="FeatureTypeDropdown" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="option1" ng-options="ft as ft.type for ft in featuretype">
        <option value="">Select a Feature Type...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="Select1" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="factory.geography.county" ng-options="c as (c|customInterpolate:option1.displayExpression) for c in option1.data" multiple>
        <option value="">Select a Feature...</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

---

---

## Old Answer

Like this?

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jpverfL3/1/)

View:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="FeatureTypeDropdown" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="option1" ng-options="ft as ft.type for ft in featuretype">
        <option value="">Select a Feature Type...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="Select1" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="factory.geography.county" ng-options="c as c[option1.displayName]+'-'+c[option1.displayCode] for c in option1.data" multiple>
        <option value="">Select a Feature...</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.featuretype = [
    { type: 'County', data:$scope.County, displayName:'CountyName', displayCode:'countyNumber' },
    { type: 'Municipality', data:$scope.Municipality, displayName:'MunicipalityName', displayCode:'MunicipalityNumber'},
    { type: 'District', data:$scope.Districts, displayName:'DistrictsName', displayCode:'DistrictsNumber'}
];
```

Comment: no not like that, sorry for not being more clear. in real world my data is coming from an outside service in JSON format and the json returned for county, municipality or District has their own field so there won't be a common displayCode as shown in my example all three json has different field so instead of one displaycode field county will have countyNumber and municipality will have municipalityNumber and so on.

Comment: @SandeepChaudhary I get it. Notice that in my example, the json items don't have the 'displayCode' attribute. I'm defining that attribute for the elements of `featuretype` and I'm assigning to that attribute the name name of the "displayCode" that they have in the json. Notice that I'm doing this: `displayCode:'countyNumber'` and `displayCode:'MunicipalityNumber'` and `displayCode:'DistrictsNumber'` in order to be able to access their respective display code. I hope that this helps

Comment: I saw that I was wondering if there is a way to combine those fields and show in drop down. I just gave an example in reality it could be more field so I was wondering if somehow in displayName only I can combine few fields and display that, even if I have to do somethign custom

Comment: @SandeepChaudhary I think that I have finally understood what you wanted! Please have a look at my updated answer, it's quite cool!